# laravel mysql to query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

i'm relatively new to laravel and i'm having issues when trying to convert this function to laravel's query builder. This is the function i've been given which also runs a python script to decrypt the database.

Comment: `i'm having issues` - what have you tried?  What happened?

Comment: @Don'tPanic so far i have this but i think i'm way off

Comment: You're expecting us to create the function for you?

Comment: @forexknight i'm not expecting anything. I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [documentation from laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) you can do something like this:

```
function call($unitId)
{
    $pfContact = DB::table('PFContact')
        ->where('UnitID', $unitId)
        ->latest() // Order by created_at
        ->first([ // Only retrieve these columns
            'Send',
            'Receive',
            'Core',
            'lock'
        ]);

    $pfReadings = DB::table('PFReadings')
        ->get();

    $rowCount = $pfReadings->count();

    foreach ($pfReadings as $i => $reading) {
        echo $i < count($reading) / $rowCount;
        foreach ($reading as $column => $value) {
            echo shell_exec(
                'python3 enc.py ' . $value 
                . ' ' . $pfContact->Send 
                . ' ' . $pfContact->Receive 
                . ' ' . $pfContact->Core 
                . ' ' . $pfContact->lock . ' ' 
                . $unitId . ' l'
            ) . '~';
        }
        echo ';';
    }
}
```

And although I do not know what arguments this pyhton script needs you should really think this through. Why would you use PHP for this and not just handle everything from the python (or php) side because this looks over complicated to me.

Comment: thanks will have a try with this. I have to use this as i'm working with another dev and this is how he has it set up

Comment: in the original post, to call the function in he does something like this, call($currentUnit, 'SELECT kWh FROM PFReadings');

Comment: what would i do in regards to the function you just posted

Comment: You _never_ want to pass sql to an function that executes it directly so I used DB::table('PFReadings') instead. It uses all columns from that table in my example. If you want just one column, you have to pass an array to the get method and put the column you want in it

Comment: thanks for trying. doesn't work though. not sure if the python script is being run

Comment: You can check if shell_exec ran successfully if it outputs null. Also, shell_exec doesn't work if php safe mode is on.

Comment: i'm getting 1~;~;~;
null

Comment: I can't help you without knowing anything about the python script or your database structure. If you want more help you should put that info in your question... @KylieWalker

Comment: Will update my question. Thanks. This all works outside of laravel when using regular mysql